# I need to optimise the following Pyspark code containing for loop

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-synapse-analytics

I have pyspark code to be implemented as following:

```
multi_row_PBL_df = inner_joined_bom_invg0_df.withColumn("BuyParentLevel", lit(None))\
                                            .withColumn('Level',col('Level').cast('int'))\
                                            .withColumn('BuyParentLevel',col('BuyParentLevel').cast('int'))
                                            
# Define the window specification to look at the previous row
windowSpec = Window.orderBy("Org Code","RecordID")
multi_row_PBL_df = multi_row_PBL_df.withColumn("Prev_MakeOrBuy", lag("Make/Buy",1,'').over(windowSpec))
multi_row_PBL_df = multi_row_PBL_df.withColumn("Prev_Level", lag("Level",1,0).over(windowSpec))

# count no of rows for iteration of MultiRow
countOfVals=multi_row_PBL_df.count()

# Iteratively update the DataFrame
for _ in range(countOfVals):  
    multi_row_PBL_df = multi_row_PBL_df.withColumn("Prev_BuyParentLevel", lag("BuyParentLevel",1,0).over(windowSpec))
    

    new_column = when(
        (col("Level") == 0) & (col("Make/Buy") == "Buy"), 0
    ).when(
        col("Prev_BuyParentLevel").isNotNull() & (col("Prev_BuyParentLevel") < col("Level")), col("Prev_BuyParentLevel")
    ).when(
        (col("Prev_MakeOrBuy") == "Buy") & (col("Prev_Level") < col("Level")), col("Prev_Level")
    ).otherwise(None)

    multi_row_PBL_df = multi_row_PBL_df.withColumn("BuyParentLevel", new_column)
```

By default spark config ,its throwing **"java.lang.stackoverflowError"** , So I tried like :
**"spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Xss100m" ,"spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Xss100m"**  . Adding these properties ,its not throwing the error ,but the its running forever.It was still running when am writing this question. Its been **2.30 hrs.**

Can Anyone optimise the above code ,in any way, I have very good compute config of **64 cores,128gigs storage with 2 Nodes**. The data which its iterating has **30k rows.**

Comment: Did you test this code for small data? Is this working code?

Comment: yes this is working for smaller dataset ,tried with 100 rows ,that has taken like 3 min

Comment: is there any partition on any columns. Because if you have partition on `Org Code` ,your `BuyParentLevel` column updates parallely on those partitions and reduces the time.

Comment: no partition. just an orderBy

Comment: will it take `Prev_BuyParentLevel` when there are different `Org_code`. Let's
say there are 2 `Org_code` and when processing iteratively there will be case that one row org code is `A` and the next is `B` will the `BuyParentLevel ` takes level of org code `A` or null? If data processing is done on `Org_code` it will be more efficient.

Comment: if the immediate org code is B ,it mus take previous row which is A

Comment: Thats just fine

Comment: Then it can not be optimized because your for loop runs in driver node and it should process all 30k records in single node even though you have a cluster of multiple nodes and cores.

Comment: Is there any thing we can check point the no of loops like for the  first 1000 loops will be one iteration ,something like that , in that way we can run parallel loops and finally union all

Comment: I thought of giving that, but you will not get the correct results. You will get null for first row in  prevBuyparentLevel if you running every 1000 loops parallely. Since you want it iteratively with previous row.

Comment: To make it parallely you need to have the situation like some no of rows belongs to particular category or partition.